# nginx ingress controller Setup on kubernetes Centos7 box

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am setting up an nginx Ingress controller as per this blog
https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller/. However I am not able to curl the nginx at port 80.

I am able to reach the default backend via the exposed node port and nginx logs show no errors.

This is my controller config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress-controller
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      serviceAccount: nginx
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.12.0

          imagePullPolicy: Always
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-controller-conf
            - --v=2
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
            - containerPort: 18080
```

This is my nginx service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    nodePort: 30000
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    port: 443
    nodePort: 30043
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress-controllere
```

Comment: Your selector labels in Deployment and Service in provided yaml is not matched. Is it a typo or not?

Comment: And, separate from Shudipta's great observation, "However I am not able to curl the nginx at port 80" is in direct conflict with what you said about the NodePort -- you will only be able to `curl :80` from _within the cluster_; all other contact with the controller must go through (in your case) `:30000`. You seem to have known that for the backend, but then ... forgot? ... for the controller.

Comment: I checked and the selector is just a typo here and as Matthew suggested I tried to curl 30000 but it gives no response.. So what I did was added a hostPort:80 to the controller and now able to curl:80. Thanks for you replies.